# how to get browser report for a bug in a web application

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, browser, report

Suppose I need to issue some bug from some web application or just a webpage, to be more informative to the dev about the specific situation where the bug occurs, I need to attach all my browser settings, plugins and etc, all the information that may be responsible​ for the bug.

How do I do this? is there a way to generate a browser report for this kind of bug?